# How can I create a SequenceFiles with `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

This is a snippet of a Gridmix code available in Hadoop MapReduce V1, but I have the following question.

They set `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat` and `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat` as the `inFormat` and `outFormat` respectively, and it also has `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` as `outKey` and `outValue`. For me, this seems that this example accepts Text files as sequence files. How can I create a SequenceFiles with `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`?

```
WEBDATASCAN("webdataScan") {
public void addJob(int numReducers, boolean mapoutputCompressed,
    boolean outputCompressed, Size size, JobControl gridmix) {
  final String prop = String.format("webdataScan.%sJobs.inputFiles", size);
  final String indir = getInputDirsFor(prop, size.defaultPath(VARCOMPSEQ));
  final String outdir = addTSSuffix("perf-out/webdata-scan-out-dir-" + size);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("-keepmap 0.2 ");
  sb.append("-keepred 5 ");
  sb.append("-inFormat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat ");
  sb.append("-outFormat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat ");
  sb.append("-outKey org.apache.hadoop.io.Text ");
  sb.append("-outValue org.apache.hadoop.io.Text ");
  sb.append("-indir ").append(indir).append(" ");
  sb.append("-outdir ").append(outdir).append(" ");
  sb.append("-r ").append(numReducers);

  String[] args = sb.toString().split(" ");
  clearDir(outdir);
  try {
    JobConf jobconf = GenericMRLoadJobCreator.createJob(
        args, mapoutputCompressed, outputCompressed);
    jobconf.setJobName("GridmixWebdatascan." + size);
    Job job = new Job(jobconf);
    gridmix.addJob(job);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up file formats and key value types. To read the plain text data, we have TextFileInputFormat. Key value types is at individual record level. Sequence output file format take the keys and values in Text format and  internally serialize the data to binary format before storing into HDFS. Internally it maintains metadata for the keys and values.

Old mapreduce api have `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package have input and output formats and `org.apache.hadoop.io` package have key and value types. Key and value types include Text, IntWritable, FloatWritable etc.